# I don't get why I am getting this error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.whootis.hmmonitor:layout/activity_main

Tags: android, android-studio

Magically I am suddenly getting this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.whootis.hmmonitor, PID: 23593
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whootis.hmmonitor/com.whootis.hmmonitor.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.whootis.hmmonitor:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #117: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.whootis.hmmonitor:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #117: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #117: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:829)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7932)
        at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:8130)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:2649)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1972)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.whootis.hmmonitor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The layout/main_activity is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and you can clearly see that line #23 is this:

```
 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

This is a basically the default layout right out of the box with Android Studio.  I have tried adding the layout_width that it is asking for but it doesn't change the error. However it does a great job of screwing up the look of the layout.

I'm totally stuck and I have no idea how to resolve this issue.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: please add your `content_main` xml as well, it might be relevant

Comment: share your include XML

Comment: what is an include XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also another line which says,

```
    Binary XML file line #117: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

Check your content_main xml as well if you haven't. Check if there are any views which are missing the layout_width.

Comment: Yes! Oh man thank you. I have stared at that for an hour.  That was exactly it!

Comment: I'm glad that helps :)